# How to find upper-left coordinate in an array of coordinates in java

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates

I searched all through internet and could not find an implementation (source code) of ready-to-use java (or it can be any programming language) function which for given an array of [x,y] coordinate pairs returns the upper-left coordinate pair.

Desired behaviour:

```
String s = getUpperLeftCoordinate([{-4455 , 3814}, {-1633 , 434}, {-1633 , 434}, {-3271 , -3687}, {-4636 , -957}, {-4636 , -957}, {1505 , -4154}, {1505 , -4154}, {1505 , -4154}]);
```

will return:

```
s="{-4455 , 3814}"
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "upper left"? Do you mean the point on the line `y - x = d` with largest d? (That kinda tells you the way to implement it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation of what `Andy Turner` had mentioned in his comment.

```
  private Point calculateTopLeftCornerPoint(Point[] points) {
    Point corner = null;
    Integer d = null;
    for (Point point : points) {
      Integer diff = point.y - point.x;
      if (d == null || (diff) > d) {
        corner = point;
        d = diff;
      }
    }
    return corner;
  }
```

> NOTE : This algorithm does not consider the possibility of two or more
>   points sitting on [**`y-x=d`**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7e5vj7ws5u) line. I will leave that part for you to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

using `java.awt.Point` for OOP

```
Point getUpperLeftCoordinate(Point... points) {
    Point mostUpperLeft = null;
    for (Point point : points) {
        if (mostUpperLeft == null) {
            mostUpperLeft = point;
        } else {
            double diffX = mostUpperLeft.getX() - point.getX();
            double diffY = point.getY() - mostUpperLeft.getY();
            if (diffX + diffY > 0) {
                mostUpperLeft = point;
            }
        }
    }
    return mostUpperLeft;
}
```